# Struts vs Zend ? Java vs PHP?

Tags: java, php

I know it's a hot question that need anwsers ^^
From my viewpoint, using Java vs PHP, is nowadays a problem of system resources (Hardware, Software, etc.).

For Java, you have to deploy J2EE Stack (JDK, AppServer, etc.) (~200M) on your server, for PHP you need to deploy a LAMP system (~100M). 
Using Java was in my opinion due to object oriented programming in web application, but today we have a lot of Object Oriented Web Language (Ruby, Python, PHP).

So the question when to choose between Java or PHP for new projects ? Maybe the community difference ?

I know that stackoverflow is not made for discussion, but it's a (good?) question that need answers (for me and for others maybe) ^^.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other constraints are usually taken into account. Things like

- development time,
- maintainance cost of the codebase
- availability of qualified programmers
- salary cost for available qualified programmers

to name a few.

Hardware and software are cheap if you compare them to the above so they tend to be less important.

Comment: Yes i'm agree with you, hardware subject was only an example.

Answer (score 14):

What are you guys talking about....

Okay JAVA has some pros, but it also has some cons. Now with PHP it is exactly the same, it has some pros, but it also has some cons.

People who say PHP doesn't have a good OO environment, well either does javascript! And really that is the heart of all web 2.0 projects; javascript. The back end today is becoming more of a resource for the front end. What you can do in JAVA now days you can do in PHP 5.3 - to some degree. If you are a good developer you will be clever enough to abstract your design to make it maintainable and if you are brillant you can match and even improve object sharing in PHP, which majority of web "designers" don't know about - or dare I say,  comprehend. Check this article out by [O'Reilly ON JAVA!](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/10/15/php_scalability.html).

I develop both in Java and PHP. I'll always use PHP for my server side and I'll use Java for Android Development, and desktop development. (By the way I have developed in java for backend development, but it take twice as long to do something in JAVA then to do it in PHP. That is why I stick to PHP.

I hear this spagetti code problem with PHP all the time. Yeah. Maybe 5 years ago! If you project ends up like this then the person, or you, is a poor programer, and you should stick to drawing pretty pictures. It is easy to separate your logic from presentation, and it is also simple to separate your business logic from you data layer. Think before you code. Don't just open up a note pad and start typing. Plan! People who fail to plan, plan to fail! Jacco you're on the money!

I see uni students all the time building code where I think, "The person who is going to end up with this guy is going to regret it". If the student just planed and documented what he was going to do then every thing would be organised and ready for scaling - again if he was good enough.

Both technologies are great and you should use what is more comfortable to you or your developers. If you go down the road where you think one is better than the other and you know nothing about that technology, well guess what? No matter what you do your projects outcome will be missed, and you'll end up having to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

I did a non-scientific performance comparison of J2EE and PHP. The comparision was to see the user experience of each system under various load conditions.

I found that PHP's response time was very slow and CPU maxed out very quickly. I understand there are some compilers that will probably help, but I wanted to make an out of the box comparison of performance of rapid development systems.

You  can read the full details here: [PHP vs J2EE: a Practical Approach](http://www.mgrecol.com/?p=71)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're doing. Choosing a language/framework without analyzing your project requirements is a bad idea.

Comment: I know but if a project is realizable with both technologies, which one do you choose ? and why ?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a language depends on what you want to do, But I am very sure that the different hard disk space requirement will be the least important aspect of your decision.

Here is a possible hint: If you want to reuse your work (or parts of it) in a desktop application, Use Java. PHP is virtually non-existent for everything except web programming.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that it is a question that can objectively be answered. In the end it is about people and what they feel more comfortable with. That is why e.g. Facebook developed a [PHP to C++ compiler](http://www.techcrunch.com/2010/02/02/facebook-hiphop-presentation/) (with which the performance benefit that Java has might become smaller, too) instead of just hiring C++ developers for doing the Job.

On the other hand, the Java platform offers some interesting new approaches like [Grails](http://grails.org/)  (which is basically a Groovy Wrapper around [Spring](http://springframework.org)) and [Lift](http://liftweb.net/), as well. That makes Frontend development faster and easier (I still find that this is a real pain with plain Java) and you can combine the benefits that other languages have with your existing Java codebase and expertise (btw. most of the Frameworks mentioned don't need a J2EE runtime environment a simple Tomcat installation with around 5M and an installed JRE should be enough). So it is not really about the Java programming language alone anymore.

And if you really can't decide at all you just run [PHP in Java](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) (works as well for [Ruby](http://jruby.org/), [Python](http://www.jython.org/), [Javascript](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) ...).

Answer (score 0):

I do not really agree on the fact that the choice of a language is related to system resources.

Hardware is cheap and we are not in a time where we need to closely look at the system resources as we used to have. Don't misunderstand me: we still do need to pay attention, but the time where people were xoring their pointers to save some space is over (luckilly).

And if your main concern is performance, then either running a JVM or an interpreted language is probably not the best option.

I do not think it is related to the orientation of the language per se either. Ok, I know, [PHP is not object oriented](http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/php-is-not-object-oriented/) but still, you can now code OO with it. You will find descent web frameworks for almost any language.

I agree with Jacco on his list.

Another aspect is indeed the culture the language refers to.

PHP is for script kiddies. Java is for serious, wearing suits business developers. Of course,  we all have many counter examples but still. Java was largely adopted by big companies, now competited by .Net. There are good reasons for this, among which the fact that it **a lot** easier to write poor code in PHP than in Java (and almost any other language). On the other hand, Java is not exactly freedom oriented.

If your project is strictly personal, you can choose whatever suits your tastes better. If you plan to develop as a team, the choice of the language will impact its general mood/way of thinking.

I would finally add some important parameters to me: fun and elegance

This may be a matter of taste here again, but I have much more fun coding in python than in C# for instance.

Answer (score 0):

PHP wins in front end in web development. Because it has much smaller development time which make things cheaper and cheaper. 
PHP will lose in mobile app development. There is no way to develop a mobile app front end with PHP. And Because its performance gap with java and other static languages, PHP will lose the back end battle. Java is old, but it has a pretty young and professional community. Check out those names: lucene, weka, hadoop,scala,cassandra, hbase, what does php provide us in back end service???????